# Running Mac application in same thread as parent script

Tags: python, macos, bash, multiprocessing

Very specific question: I am writing a (Python) script that should

1. generate a temporary file.
2. Launch an image viewer.
3. Upon closing the viewer, deletes the tmp file.

In linux, this would work fine because I'd open a subprocess from Python and run the following

`eog myimg.png; rm myimg.png`

However, the story is different on Mac. The `open` command launches in a different process. If I use `/Applications/Preview.app/MacOS/Preview`, I get a weird permissions issue. This persists if I kill my script, leaving the file, then fire up Terminal.app:

Running `open myimg.png` works as expected. Running `/Applications/Preview.app/MacOS/Preview myimg.png` gets the same permissions error. (Meaning to say- it's not actually a file permissions error). And FWIW, the file is 444 anyway.

My guess is that the open command runs applications from a different user, which is allowed to access parent directories that my user is not using, something like that.

Anyway, anyone know exactly what's going on, and what a viable solution would be? Thank you!

**EDIT**
Current code is

```
name = '/var/folders/qy/w9zq1h3d22ndc2d_7hgwj2zm0000gn/T/tmpDHRg2T.png'
viewer_command = 'open'
subprocess.Popen(viewer_command + ' ' + name +' ; rm ' + name, shell=True)
```

Comment: You need to distinguish between threads and processes.  Using `open` (the Mac command) means separate processes, not just a separate thread.  Threads work within a single process, using a single binary. What you're describing is multiple processes - on both Linux and Mac.  You say "a weird permissions issue" -- what does that mean? What exactly is the message?

Comment: Thanks, you're right about threads/process. Fixed that. Error is `The file “tmp5ZKcAr.png” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it. To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but are you looking for `-W`? ` -W  Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited.  Use with the -n flag to allow open to
         function as an appropriate app for the $EDITOR environment variable.`

Comment: Yes, of course! I should have looked at the man page. That will work for the time being. Thank you very much for that pointer. Although creates the slightly frustrating bug that the app has to be shut down entirely. I guess I'm wondering if it's possible to replicate linux-like process management for mac gui applications.

Comment: Why are you running the `rm` along with the `open` call?

Comment: Because it's just a temporary file that I don't want to save - I want to clean up after myself. Open to alternative solutions though.

Comment: Set an `atexit` handler http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html to remove the tmp file or use a try..finally. But mixing the opening with the cleaning is just asking for problems.

Comment: atexit doesn't work because the python script terminates immediately, the script itself isn't supposed to wait for the viewer to close. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

TMP=$(mktemp sperry.XXXXXX.jpg)

echo "Made $TMP"

IMG="/Users/sean_perry/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures/Photo on 6-8-12 at 4.37 PM.jpg"

cp "$IMG" $TMP

open "$TMP"

rm $TMP
```

This script works just fine on my OSX machine.
So does

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

subprocess.call(["open", "/Users/me/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures/Photo on 6-8-12 at 4.37 PM.jpg"])
```

Can you post yours?

Comment: Did you actually run the first one? For me, it launches an empty instance of Preview, because the image is deleted as soon as the application is launched. The second one is close to what I've got, but doesn't demonstrate the problem. I'll edit question with my code.

Comment: Yes, it does work. The `open` happens and then the file is removed but the app has already loaded the image.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway, anyone know exactly what's going on, and what a viable solution would be?

It's hard to say for certain without more details (like how your script is being run, and what error message you are getting), but it seems likely that your script is either running as a different user from the console user, or is not running within the login context.

Contexts are an unusual feature of Mac OS X, and are documented in Apple's [Kernel Programming Guide ("Bootstrap Contexts")](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/conceptual/kernelprogramming/contexts/contexts.html). In brief, a process that is not launched from a process descended from the login window (for instance, a process that is launched through SSH) will not have the necessary access to services within that context, such as the WindowServer, to start a desktop application.